# Button not getting proper width android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` with rows containing `Button`. I want all the buttons to be of the same width but they act like their width is `match_parent` when they are rendered even though I've given them a specific width. They are not handled anywhere in Java, so the problem should lie in the XML only.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mridulahuja.kudamm.activities.ComponentDetailsActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/light_green_background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.mridulahuja.kudamm.tools.ExpandableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtComponentInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="component info"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDataAtAGlance"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                    android:text="Data at a glance"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDimensionsAtAGlance"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                    android:text="Dimensions at a glance"
                    />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDownloadPdfCatalogue"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                    android:text="PDF Catalogue"
                    />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the view rendered on Android Studio:

[image]

And this is the view rendered on mobile: (see the first button => this is happening will all buttons when I make their XML similar)

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: the `dp` value change from device to another, you have to make multiple dimens.xml files for each density .

Comment: Is it necessary using table structure? You may have to use another view elements, like Constraints / RelativeLayout. These are easier to manipulate your widgets.

Comment: @Ibrahim this is happening even I give it a width of `50dp` which is very less

Answer (score 1):

`dp` will vary from device to device. As a workaround, what you can do is, set the `width` of all the buttons to `match_parent` and add `marginLeft` and `marginRight` on each. 
Or Use multiple `dimens.xml` files for various densities, as suggested by Ibrahim in the comment.

Comment: margin also use dp

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:layout_gravity="center"` from each button, you have already specified `android:gravity="center"` for the TableRow (which is doing the same thing).

By `android:layout_gravity="center"` you are saying the button should be centered inside its parent, and by `android:gravity="center"` you are saying the child of this element(which is the button) should be centered inside it. Mr. Android was confused, so it changed the width you set to `wrap_content` and centered the button.

Note: Your first button doesn't specify layout_gravity and that is why it is 
      displayed as expected